# How can I convert a System.Array to a System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray?

Tags: c#

When I try an implicit conversion I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Array' to 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<Type>'
```

When I try to explicitly cast I get these errors:

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Array' to 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray'

Cannot convert to static type 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray'
```

Comment: Looks like you're confusing `ImmutableArray` with `ImmutableArray<T>`, but since you haven't shown any code, it's hard to say.

Comment: You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ImmutableArray.Create<T>([])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn628180%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) to do the conversion:

```
var immutableArray = ImmutableArray.Create(yourArray);
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using. Thanks. I had another issue where I was using System.Array vs MyType[].

Answer (score 0):

IReadOnlyCollection is what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ImmutableArray<T> Create<T>(T[] items)
            {

                if (items.length == 0)
                {
                    // Avoid allocating an array.
                    return Create<T>();
                }

                var array = new T[items.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                {
                    array[i] = items[i];
                }

                return new ImmutableArray<T>(array);
            }
```

Using the code above you can create an ImmutableArray. By calling

```
return Create(yourArrayHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 8 Preview there are several new methods that access the internal constructor and thus it has a high performance and no memory consumption.

Use [`ImmutableCollectionsMarshal.AsImmutableArray<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.immutablecollectionsmarshal.asimmutablearray?view=net-8.0):

```cs
ImmutableArray<T> im = ImmutableCollectionsMarshal.AsImmutableArray(array);
```

And this is the benchmark - smart is the new way.

[image]